Backfill the missing values
suppose to have the following:

data DB1;
  input ID Index;
cards;
0001  .    
0001  1 
0003  .
0003  5
0004  .
0004  .
0004  2
;


data DB2;
  input ID Index;
cards;
0001  1    
0001  1 
0003  5
0003  5
0004  2
0004  2
0004  2
;

DB1 has an Index at the last available row of each ID. Is there a way to fill the missing values before the last row of the ID with the value in the last row of the ID? DB2 is the desired output.
Thank you in advance

You can use serial DOW loops.  The essence of the DOW loop technique is having a SET statement inside a DO loop
Example:
For this simple example wherein there are only two columns, the second DOW does not contain a SET.  In reality when the have data set has satellite columns (columns other than the BY group and the backfill), the second loop MUST have a SET as well.
data want;
  if 0 then set have ; * prep PDV ;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (not missing(index)) ;
    set have ;
  end ;
  backfill = index ;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_ ;
    index = backfill ;
    output ;
  end ;
  drop backfill ;
run ;


Based on @Richard DOW loop skill, you can read the last value of each by-group and put them on every row of current by-group.
data db2;
  set db1;
  by id;

  if first.id then do until(last.id);
    set db1(rename=(index=last_index));
    by id;
  end;
  if index=. then index=last_index;
run;

